# Extracting data after filtering substring using Python

Tags: python, split, substring

I have a JSON file of DNS traffic with this format

```
{
    "index": {
        "_type": "answer_query", 
        "_id": 0, 
        "_index": "index_name"
    }
}

{
    "answer_section": " ", 
    "query_type": "A", 
    "authority_section": "com. 172 IN SOA a.xxxx-xxxx.net. nstld.xxxx-xxxxcom. 1526440480 1800 900 604800 86400", 
    "record_code": "NXDOMAIN", 
    "ip_src": "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
    "response_ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
    "date_time": "2018-05-16T00:57:20Z", 
    "checksum": "CORRECT", 
    "query_name": "xx.xxxx.com.", 
    "port_src": 50223, 
    "question_section": "xx.xxxx.com. IN A", 
    "answer_count_section": 0
}
```

I need to extract the data which has the number after space (in the example, it would be 172) in `authority_section` of less than 300 and disregard those which doesn't meet the requirement, then write the output to another JSON file.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Show what you've attempted.

Comment: Also write an example for the expected output (JSON) for this case.

Comment: @l'L'l I am still new to working with Python so I don't have any presentable code yet.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi The output should have similar structure with the input JSON file, only the data which have the number above 300 would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming stack1.txt is the file you posted. This will write a new file stack2.txt which omits that "authority_section" line if the "value after the space" is >= 300. This solution doesn't require parsing json, but it is very dependent on the format of the data being consistent.

```
import os
with open('stack2.txt','w') as new_file:
    old_file = open('stack1.txt').readlines()
    delete_file = False
    for line in old_file:
        if not (line.strip().startswith('"authority_section"') and int(line.split(':')[1].split()[1]) >= 300):
            new_file.write(line)
        else:
            delete_file = True
if delete_file:
    os.remove('stack2.txt')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! This does write another file with similar structure as the input, but I am still having the data with the value above 300. I am not sure if this is the case, but is it possible that the filter should be after the second space in the "authority_section" line?

Comment: When I change 172 --> 304 it omits that line in the new file, as expected. Using a regular expression is probably a better answer if you can't count on your data format being consistent...

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant I want to filter those with value <= 300. It is working, thanks! But is there any way to delete the whole data, not only the authority section, if it is not within the requirement?

Comment: Delete the file afterwards? ^

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json
import re

data = (
    """
    {
         "answer_section": " ",
         "query_type": "A",
         "authority_section": "com. 172 IN SOA a.xxxx-xxxx.net. nstld.xxxx-xxxxcom. 1526440480 1800 900 604800 86400",
         "record_code": "NXDOMAIN",
         "ip_src": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
         "response_ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
         "date_time": "2018-05-16T00:57:20Z",
         "checksum": "CORRECT",
         "query_name": "xx.xxxx.com.",
         "port_src": 50223,
         "question_section": "xx.xxxx.com. IN A",
         "answer_count_section": 0
    }
    """
)


json_data = json.loads(data)
print('BEFORE: ', json_data)

r = re.compile('^\s([1-2]\d\d|[1-9]\d|[1-9])\s$')


found = False
key_to_delete = None

for key, value in json_data.items():
    if value == 0:
        pass
    else:
        tmp = str(value)
        for i in range(0, len(tmp)):
            if r.match(tmp[i:i+3]):
                found = True
                key_to_delete = key
                print('FOUND 1: ', value)
            elif r.match(tmp[i:i+4]):
                found = True
                key_to_delete = key
                print('FOUND 2: ', value)
            elif r.match(tmp[i:i+5]):
                found = True
                key_to_delete = key
                print('FOUND 3: ', value)

if found:
    json_data.pop(key_to_delete)

print('RESULT: ', json_data)
```

I am using regular expressions in my answer. Read about the regex for more details.